# Java Cloning - deep copy and shallow copy

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Deep copy vs Shallow Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657810/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy)
>   [In Java, what is a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy)
>   [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Can you please tell me what does it mean by cloning in java? what is deep copy and shallow copy, please explain with examples

Comment: You really should search first for these kinds of questions. This has been beaten to death. Multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading of Item 11 in [Effective Java Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)