# Use structure binding when iterator a vector of std::pair<string, some_struct >*

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdmap, structured-bindings

the below code shows how a structure binding normally works.
It provides a more descriptive name comparing to "first", "second".

```
map<string, string> sites;
sites.insert({ "GeeksforGeeks", "Coding Resources" });

for (auto& [key, value] : sites)
{
   cout << key.c_str() << " " << value.c_str() << endl;
}
```

Now I have a `std::vector<pair<std::string, People>* > vec;`
`People` here is a class, and `string` is his/her nicknames.

Code like following does not work, because `vec` contains pointers.

```
for (auto & [kay, value] : vec) {}
```

Then what should I do to use the structure binding to provide more descriptive names?

---

**Edit**:

I use pointers because I want to avoid copies.
This is how I build the  `std::vector<pair<std::string, People>* > vec;`.

I have a `unordered_map<string, People>`, I need to print the results to clients in a deterministic way, but traversing order of a map is random.
So, I create `vec` and sort the `vec` by the string, which is the key.

If not using pointers, lots of copies will happen if I want to sort.

Comment: you'll have to iterate over the pointers and defer the structured binding to within the loop, there is no syntax for dereferencing in structured bindings nor range-based for loops

Comment: I use pointer it is because I want to avoid copies.

Comment: Did you mean that you do not what to make a [deep copy `std::pair<std::string, People>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657810/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy) rather just a copy of the pointers what the vec hold. Sounds not good. Anyways, that is another issue/question.

Comment: I updated the problem. It provides more information. :)

Comment: If the answer helped you solved the issue, you could mark it as accepted. Otherwise let me know, what is missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to the `std::vector<pair<std::string, People>* > vec;`

```
for (std::pair<std::string, People>* pairPtr : vec) // iterate via pair-ptrs
{
   if (pairPtr) // if the pointer is valid!
   {
      const auto& [key, people] = *pairPtr;
      // do something with the key and vale!
   }
}
```

If the pair-pointer pointing to the array, you need to iterate through and do the above.

BTW, have a look at to the [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) rather raw pointer in C++17.